# Sending multiple cookies using Fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send two cookies using Fetch in Javascript.
This is my function:

```
var cid_and_auth = process.argv[2];
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


function usePairService()
{
    cid = cid_and_auth.split(" ")[1];
    auth = cid_and_auth.split(" ")[0];
    (async () => {
        await fetch(AUTHENTICATIONURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': CONTENTTYPE,
                'wpay-meta': userPairwpaymeta,
                'cookie': 'cid'=cid,'auth'= auth,
            },
            body: JsonBody,
        })
        });;

}
```

I am trying to send cookies in the header, but it's giving an error, saying invalid left-hand die in expression. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `'cid'=cid` tries to assign the value of `cid` to the **string** value `'cid'`. You cannot assign to a string, hence the error.

Comment: try 'cookie': `\`'cid'=${cid},'auth'= ${auth}\``, use back ticks. read more about string literals

Comment: @FelixKling any idea how the syntax will be? I am trying to assign cid and auth to cookies.

Comment: @NeelDebnath I did this: 'cookie': 'cid'=${cid},'auth'= ${auth}. Not working, its showing expression expected.

Comment: Please check I have added back tick in the beginning and at the end of the code or check Felix's ans @Nilu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'cid'=cid` tries to assign the value of `cid` to the **string** value `'cid'`. You cannot assign to a string, hence the error.

You have to build up a string of `<key>=<value>;` pairs. If you have each value in a variable you can either manually build the string, e.g. using template literals:

```
{
  // ...
  Cookie: `cid=${cid};auth=${auth}`,
 }
```

or you could create an object from those variables and programmatically create the string (which makes it a bit easier to add more values later on):

```
const cookieData = {cid, auth};
// ...
{
  // ...
  Cookie: Object.entries(cookieData)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join(';'),
}
```

Comment: FYI - You might want to use `encodeURIComponent` on the `key` and `value` incase they include `=` or `;` symbols.